# How can I limit the number of characters in a WP Simple Pay field in WordPress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins

I've tried adding jquery to the header and footer, but can't get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#simpay-799-text-7").attr("maxlength", 4)
});
</script>
```

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?  I've double checked that jquery is used on the site... it's a WordPress site.  Thank you!

Comment: It should work fine. Do you have more code to show?

Comment: The page is here: https://eastangelfriends.org/support/bricks-and-pavers-2020/

You'll see the stripe payment form in the page, and the javascript is in the footer. I've tried it on the header as well.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the jQuery you are using. Try to replace ``$`` with ``jQuery``. For example: ``jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... }``.

Comment: That's it.... thank you!!!  How do I mark you as the correct answer?

Comment: Good. Don't worry about it. Sometimes a comment is enough to help someone. :)